# Can I add amounts from multiple tables in hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I would like to perform a query in HQL similar to this in SQL:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYER +
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPANIES
       ) 
FROM DUAL
```

When I add "FROM DUAL" to the query I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DUAL is not mapped
```

And if I leave off the "FROM DUAL" I get:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, subqueries need their own set of parentheses, so try this:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYER) +
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPANIES)
       )
```

If that doesn't work, resort to a `from` clause:

```
SELECT e.cnt + c.cnt
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM EMPLOYER
     ) e CROSS JOIN +
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM COMPANIES
     ) c
```

Comment: The sql was just as an example, i'm not getting stuck on the sql syntax, i'm having trouble with the hibernate side of it - hibernate either doesn't recognize dual or doesn't let me leave off the from clause

Comment: `dual` is most commonly associated with Oracle, although it is also allowed in MySQL.  SQL Server, Postgres, Teradata, and MySQL allow you to leave out the `from` clause.  DB2 uses `sysdummy1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't join the Company and Employee tables you'd better run two queries:

```
int companyCount = ((Number) getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from Company").uniqueResult()).intValue();
int employeeCount = ((Number) getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from Employee").uniqueResult()).intValue();
int totalCount = companyCount + employeeCount;
```

The (Number) is needed since PostgreSQL returns a BigInteger while HDSQLDB returns an Integer, but both are subclasses of Number.